# Movie about an astronaut in space, thinking he is communicating with his people, but is actually being tricked

Tags: story-identification, movie, astronauts

Inside a space capsule, talking over a radio, thinking he is talking to his wife and his fellow astronauts, but he is really talking to foreign intelligence agents.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, roughly where in space was the capsule? In Earth's orbit? And was this set around the present day, or in a more futuristic world?

Comment: Movie, or tv show? I think there was an Outer Limits (or similar show) episode like that.